# java swing close window without exiting app

Tags: java, swing, button, exit

I have a little frame where I ask user & password. This frame will be opened clicking over a button in a main window.

Then I have two buttons: ok and cancel.

When I click on "cancel" button, I need to close this frame without exiting the app.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use either Frame.hide() or Frame.dispose().
I would also recommend to look into JDialog or JOptionPane

Correction: hide() is deprecated. SetVisible(false) should be used instead

Comment: ok, and what if my click handler is into a different class extarnal to the frame?

Comment: you have to pass a reference to the frame to the click handler (in the constructor)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a cleaner way is just change the setDefaultCloseOperation from EXIT_ON_CLOSE to DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE :

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call setVisible(false) on the frame.

You might also want to call setDefaultCloseOperation on the frame passing in HIDE_ON_CLOSE (info here: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29).  That will prevent the app from going away if they user hits the "X" on the JFrame to close it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `this.dispose();` in the action listener method when the username/password succeeds.  eg:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    if(ae.getSource()=="button you press to confirm username/password"){
        if(userNameTf.getText().equals(username)&&isPassword(passwordTf.getPassword())){
            new "window to be opened upon success"
            this.dispose(); // calls dispose on this object ie. 
                                            // the login window 
        }
        else{
            userNameTf.setText("");
            passwordTf.setText("");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                    "Username and/or password is incorrect!",
                    "Attention!",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

}
```

If you are using inner classes to handle the events
just replace 'this.dispose()' with Super_Class_Name.this.dispose();

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you do not:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: this is not my problem buddy :)

Answer (score 2):

setVisible method does not release memory resources and should be used only when the form is to be used again.

The **dispose** method Releases all of the native screen resources used by this Window, its subcomponents, and all of its owned children. That is, the resources for these Components will be destroyed, any memory they consume will be returned to the OS, and they will be marked as undisplayable.

Answer (score 1):

Make a function in outer class where you are implementing the `JFrame` (you need to close on pressing cancel button).
Write `this.setVisible(false);` in the implementation of that function.
Finally call this function in the `ActionListener` implementation when you want to close it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways but these two ways are most usable one
1. write **`this.setVisible(false)`** in inside implemented **`ActionListener`**
Or
2. write **`this.dispose()`** inside implemented **`ActionListener`**.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: This is exactly what the accepted answer says.  There's no reason to add an answer just to repeat what's already accepted.