# how to close a single class that contains frame in java

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

i wan to close the particular classname.java window alone.

I am developing a GUI using netbeans.
I created a main class and defined a button , when clicked will load 
new classname().setVisible(true);

this classname.java contains a frame with components to get the input

now when i use System.exit(); in classname.java all the windows are closed

i wan to close the particular classname.java window alone.
how can i do so ?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   System.exit(0); // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Comment: right, this is actually a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573317/java-swing-close-window-without-exiting-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to hide it use

```
setVisible(false);
```

Or to dispose use

```
dispose();
```

Answer (score 2):

USE `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`

```
JFrame f = JFrame();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`
```

Comment: using DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE also closes all the open windows

Comment: @radish see this link now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944446/close-one-jframe-without-closing-another

Comment: First do some research before negating an answer

Comment: You have negated my answer without any delay, so i insist that you do the same to read it and understand it and correct the wrongs

Comment: Even see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573317/java-swing-close-window-without-exiting-app

Comment: sorry that negation was by mistake

Comment: Its ok, seeing a negation instead of an upvote on the right answer is sometimes hurting

Comment: Thanks for your time to reply PhilNerd's answer helped me to get what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you keep a reference to the `classname` instance you created, and call either `setVisible(false)` or `dispose()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

When you do that,it will close all the windows opened, it means that the app will be ended.
I think you should use this method: `windowClosing()`. You can get more information about this, here:[link](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/awt/AwtCloseButtonEvent.shtml)

I hope that is helpful to you.
Regards, Gil